# how can i use SetState in Riverpod in flutter?

Tags: flutter, setstate, riverpod, state-management

when i use StateFullWidget then i can use SetState. But i need this code in riverpod. But in Riverpod ther is no setState. Please write this code for riverpod.i want to when i click circuler avatar then image will change. this code useing SetState but i need it in riverpod

```
class UploadImage extends StatefulWidget {
  const UploadImage({super.key});

  @override
  State<UploadImage> createState() => _UploadImageState();
}

class _UploadImageState extends State<UploadImage> {
  String? downloadUrl;
  File? image;

  void showScanbar({required String content}) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(content)));
  }

  Future picImage(ImageSource source) async {
    try {
      final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);
      if (image == null) return;
      final imageTemporary = File(image.path);
      setState(() => this.image = imageTemporary);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('Faild to pick Image $e');
    }
  }

  Future uploadImage() async {
    Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('image');
    await ref.putFile(image!);
    downloadUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    print(downloadUrl);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Upload image'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              image != null
                  ? CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: FileImage(image!),
                      radius: 40,
                    )
                  : CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                        'https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/84/165/png-clipart-united-states-avatar-organization-information-user-avatar-service-computer-wallpaper-thumbnail.png',
                      ),
                      radius: 40,
                    ),
              Positioned(
                  left: 40,
                  bottom: -10,
                  child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        picImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.add_photo_alternate)))
            ],
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (image != null) {
                  uploadImage()
                      .whenComplete(() => showScanbar(content: 'Completed'));
                } else {
                  showScanbar(content: 'No image');
                }
              },
              child: Text(
                'Upload',
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I need it in Riverpod Because i want to when i click circuler avatar then image will change. this code useing SetState but i need it in riverpod

Comment: Your context should never go anywhere near a riverpod provider.  Riverpod is a data layer... the M in MVC.  Your views should react based on how the models change.